# rvm requirements 'Failed loading requirements for osx_brew!'

Tags: rvm, homebrew

I attempted to install Ruby 2.0.0-p0 on my Mac (OS X 10.8.3) today, which failed with some issues around gem installation (unfortunately I didn't keep the error logs).

Since then I've been having problems with RVM and Brew - if I try to do anything with RVM it just prints the error message:

```
Failed loading requirements for osx_brew!
```

I've tried removing and reinstalling both RVM and Brew, but with no success, and I can't find any reference to this message on the internet. Anybody got any idea why it might be happening, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same problem, I needed to update rvm -- make sure to read requirements afterward;

```
rvm get stable
rvm requirements
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with last version of RVM.. I having the same issue... You need to try to install the stable version...

rvm get stable

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug and is already fixed, update with:

```
rvm get head
rvm install ruby --autolibs=4
```